# Why am I getting a runtime error of "DeformGroup 'Bone.002' not in object 'Cube'"?

Tags: scripting, rigging, vertex-groups

I'm trying to batch dissolve a chain of bones and merge the remaining vertex group, essentially unsubdividing the chain. I'm testing this on a subdivided cube with a chain of 8 bones. However, I'm getting this error when I call `obj.vertex_groups.remove(vg2)` to remove the second vertex group. What is going wrong and how can it be fixed?

```
  File "\Text", line 50, in <module>
  File "\Text", line 42, in main
  File "\Text", line 17, in merge_vertex_groups
RuntimeError: Error: DeformGroup 'Bone.002' not in object 'Cube'
```

My code:

```
import bpy

def merge_bones(bone1, bone2):
    bone1.tail = bone2.tail
    bpy.ops.armature.delete(type='BONE')

def merge_vertex_groups(obj, vg1, vg2):
    print(obj)
    mod = obj.modifiers.new("mix", "VERTEX_WEIGHT_MIX")
    mod.vertex_group_a = vg1.name
    mod.vertex_group_b = vg2.name
    mod.mix_mode = "ADD"
    mod.mix_set = "B"
    
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=mod.name)
    
    obj.vertex_groups.remove(vg2)

def main():
    mesh = None
    arm = None
    
    #Select mesh and armature, and go into armature's edit mode.
    for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        match obj.type:
            case 'MESH':
                mesh = obj
            case 'ARMATURE':
                arm = obj.data
    
    selected_bones = [bone for bone in arm.edit_bones if bone.select]
    vertex_groups = [mesh.vertex_groups.get(bone.name) for bone in selected_bones]

    
    #merge vertex groups first
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT', toggle=False)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = mesh
    for i in range(1, len(selected_bones),2):
        vg1 = vertex_groups[i-1]
        vg2 = vertex_groups[i]
        
        merge_vertex_groups(mesh, vg1, vg2)
        
    #merge bones last
#    for i in range(1, len(selected_bones)):
#       bone1 = selected_bones[i-1]
#       bone2 = selected_bones[i]
#       merge_bones(bone1, bone2)        

main()
```

Using Blender 3.6.1
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first `bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT', toggle=False)` is missing in def main() before creating list with selected bones.

Behind the scene all variables are nothing more than pointers to datablocks in memory. With `bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=mod.name)` in function `def merge_bones()` the pointers of the vertexgroups are changed. To see what happen insert IDchecks before and after applying the modifier:

```
def merge_vertex_groups(obj, vg1, vg2):
    print(obj)
    mod = obj.modifiers.new("mix", "VERTEX_WEIGHT_MIX")
    mod.vertex_group_a = vg1.name
    mod.vertex_group_b = vg2.name
    mod.mix_mode = "ADD"
    mod.mix_set = "B"
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=mod.name)

    print([id(v) for v in obj.vertex_groups]) # check ID
    obj.vertex_groups.remove(vg2)
    print([id(v) for v in obj.vertex_groups]) # check ID
```

Now you can see that the memory addresses of the vertexgroups have changed. You need to get the new adress for vg2 with `vg2 = obj.vertex_groups[vg2.name]` before removing the vertexgroup:

```
def merge_vertex_groups(obj, vg1, vg2):
    print(obj)
    mod = obj.modifiers.new("mix", "VERTEX_WEIGHT_MIX")
    mod.vertex_group_a = vg1.name
    mod.vertex_group_b = vg2.name
    mod.mix_mode = "ADD"
    mod.mix_set = "B"
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=mod.name)

    vg2 = obj.vertex_groups[vg2.name]         # add
    obj.vertex_groups.remove(vg2)
```